# Get all items from Repeater's datasource when using pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, custom-controls, repeater

I've got a Repeater control, bound to a `PagedDataSource`, which datasource is a list of custom controls I've made. These custom controls contains a couple of text boxes.

I have a save button, and when it is clicked I want to save the data in all the custom controls to a database, no matter which page they are on - but currently I only got access to the custom controls displayed on the current page.

What I've tried to do is to, in the `btnSave_Click` event, create a new temporary datasource equal to the current one, except its not a `PagedDataSource`. That way my repeater contains all custom controls - BUT - the changes made in the textbox fields are no longer available. I then tried to add JavaScript onchange events on the textboxes in the custom control, so that a postback would be fired whenever text was changed, and the property in the user control codebehind would be updated. This didnt work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm actually wondering about this as well!

Answer (score 0):

save the changed values on each page index changing event (or prev /next buttons) into your persistance object (List)

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1611/how-to-select-multiple-records-from-multiple-pages-of-the-gridview-and

Comment: Im sorry for the downvotes you received. Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, by the time people started answering, I've begun working on some other stuff. So i wont be able to see if your answers will work until later

Answer (score 0):

The reason your non-PagedDataSource is empty is because the changes in your text box exist in the client and not on the server - you'll need to synchronise the values from your controls with the empty slots in your repeater.

Answer (score -1):

The Repeater does not have built-in Pagination (like the GridView or other complex controls) so it does not offer events such as the PageIndexChanging event. I assume therefore, that you have your own Page navigation implementation. You should therefore call the function you have presented within that implemented function.

Comment: He obviously has the events handled. Most likely with Prev/Next buttons. Your answer provides no value.

Answer (score -1):

Try Using a generic List and Skip and Take methods of that